# SQL 2012 UPDATING column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to alter the employees pay using data from a separate table to determine if the employee has a specific job classification.

It's telling me I have an invalid column name.  But the column exists.

Any help is appreciated, while I continue to look for a solution.

Thanks guys.

```
USE HARTKudlerFineFoods

SELECT dbo.tblEmployee.empSalary,
       dbo.tblJobTitle.jobJobClassification
FROM   dbo.tblEmployee
       FULL OUTER JOIN dbo.tblJobTitle
                    ON dbo.tblEmployee.empJobID = dbo.tblJobTitle.jobJobID

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

UPDATE dbo.tblEmployee
SET    empSalary = empSalary * .05946
WHERE  ( [jobJobClassification] = '%ist' );
```

Comment: (1) This query doesn't make sense.  (2) Is this intended to be two queries?  (3) Why are you reducing salaries 94.154%?

Answer (score 3):

I am guessing you really want:

```
UPDATE e
    SET empSalary = empSalary * (1 + 0.05946)
    FROM dbo.tblEmployee e JOIN
         dbo.tblJobTitle jt
         ON e.empJobID = jt.jobJobID
    WHERE jt.jobJobClassification like '%ist';
```

This will give all the people whose job title ends in `ist` a raise of 5.946%.

Comment: +1 On behalf of all Kudler Fine Food employees that narrowly avoided a big salary drop.